# Open a new window in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM .I have a window Demo.xaml which has menu, under menu i have sub menus.I want to open sub menu window i.e Test.Xaml on the click of submenu using MVVM approach.
I made an object of Test Window but it didn't showed "Show" property.
I also tried by using Delegate Commands but i failed.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say MVVM approach, do you mean the ViewModel should be able to spawn a new window?

Answer (score 0):

The most common MVVM approach to solve your problem is to bind the submenu item's "Command" to a property in the ViewModel which implements ICommand. Then, in the command's execution, you can open your window of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ICommand` - when working with MVVM using `RelayCommand` is best practice.

See my example below:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<MenuItem Header="Settings" Command="{Binding CmdOpenSetting}" >                    
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="..\Resources\if_Gnome-Preferences-System.png" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0,0,-5,0" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Singelton not needed
    MainWindowViewModel.Instance = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.DataContext = MainWindowViewModel.Instance;

    //Also works
    this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
private RelayCommand _commandOpenSettings;

public ICommand CmdOpenSetting
{
    get
    {
        if(_commandOpenSettings.IsNull())
        {
            _commandOpenSettings = new RelayCommand(param => OpenSettings());
        }
        return _commandOpenSettings;
    }
}
```

**Note** you may have to adjust the `CmdOpenSetting` according to you implementation of `RelayCommand`

See [Example RelayCommand](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/)